# PHP Accessing an item in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array:

```
Cart Object
(
    [event_list] => Array
        (
            [15] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [event_id] => 15
                    [event_name] => North Pole Express 2014
                    [event_date] => 2014-12-06
                    [event_time] => 10:40:00
                    [event_ort_id] => 1
                    [ort_name] => Tanfield Railway
                    [ort_city] => Newcastle upon Tyne
                    [event_order_limit] => 0
                    [event_use_alt] => 
                )

            [14] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [event_id] => 14
                    [event_name] => North Pole Express 2014
                    [event_date] => 2014-11-30
                    [event_time] => 10:40:00
                    [event_ort_id] => 1
                    [ort_name] => Tanfield Railway
                    [ort_city] => Newcastle upon Tyne
                    [event_order_limit] => 0
                    [event_use_alt] => 
                )

            [13] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [event_id] => 13
                    [event_name] => North Pole Express 2014
                    [event_date] => 2014-11-29
                    [event_time] => 10:40:00
                    [event_ort_id] => 1
                    [ort_name] => Tanfield Railway
                    [ort_city] => Newcastle upon Tyne
                    [event_order_limit] => 0
                    [event_use_alt] => 
                )

        )

    [cat_list] => Array
        (
            [138] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [cat_id] => 138
                    [category_event_id] => 15
                    [cat_name] => Child - 4:00 pm
                    [cat_price] => 12.00
                    [cat_numbering] => none
                )

            [120] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [cat_id] => 120
                    [category_event_id] => 14
                    [cat_name] => Child - 4:00 pm
                    [cat_price] => 12.00
                    [cat_numbering] => none
                )

            [102] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [cat_id] => 102
                    [category_event_id] => 13
                    [cat_name] => Child - 4:00 pm
                    [cat_price] => 12.00
                    [cat_numbering] => none
                )

        )

    [disc_list] => Array
        (
        )

    [items] => Array
        (
            [4] => PlaceItem Object
                (
                    [id] => 4
                    [cart] => Cart Object
 *RECURSION*
                    [event_id] => 14
                    [category_id] => 120
                    [seats] => Array
                        (
                            [26151] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [seat_id] => 26151
                                    [seat_row_nr] => 0
                                    [seat_nr] => 0
                                    [seat_ts] => 1388769219
                                    [discount_id] => 0
                                )

                        )

                    [ts] => 
                    [created] => 2014-01-03T16:43:39+00:00
                    [expired] => 
                )

        )

    [ts] => 1388769219
)
```

I need to be able to access the 'Items' Key.

However everything I have tried so far has failed. I suspect I am missing something really obvious.

What would be the best way to access these items?

Comment: So, what have you tried that has not worked?  We can't tell you what you are missing unless you show us what you've tried.

Comment: Since Cart is an object, have you tried `$cart->items`?

Comment: its an abject not an array: $myobj->items

Answer (score 3):

`Cart` is not an array, it's an Object.

```
$cart = new Cart();
$cart->items; // <-- this is an array (of PlaceItems)
```

Comment: Hi All, Ok, tired all the comments and I still can't get anywhere. I have used a variable to breakdown a bigger array/object. This is my current PHP $cCart = $_SESSION['_SMART_cart']; print_r($cCart); This is what I have used to extract the above array. Am I missing something really obvious?

Answer (score 1):

Since `$cart` is an object you need to use object notation to access it, the arrays are underneath that:

```
forach ($cart->items as $key=>$value) {
  //...
}
```

Update from your comment:

```
$items=$_SESSION['_SMART_cart']->items;
foreach ($items as $key=>$value) {
   //...
}
```

Comment: Hi All, 

Ok, tired all the comments and I still can't get anywhere.

I have used a variable to breakdown a bigger array/object. This is my current PHP


    $cCart = $_SESSION['_SMART_cart'];
    
     print_r($cCart);

This is what I have used to extract the above array. Am I missing something really obvious?